# How to Retrieve a slash Command's ID using Discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I am working on a Discord bot and trying to create a clickable slash command link. However, I'm having trouble finding the ID the a slash command

```
command = self.bot.tree.get_command("rank")
```

```
await message.reply(f"To view your rank, please click here </rank:{command.id}> ")
```

Unfortunately, I discovered that **`command`** does not have an **`id`** attribute, which is causing issues in generating the clickable link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_command()` function returns `bot.command` not `bot.tree.command`.
You need the `fetch_commands()` function for that.

Here is the example:

```
@bot.command()
async def commandid(ctx,name):
    commands = await bot.tree.fetch_commands()
    for cmd in commands:
        if cmd.name == name:
            await ctx.send(cmd.id)
```